# Snapshot failure with Sonar in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

This is the second time I'm experiencing this problem with Sonar version 3.7.4. Previous time I just created a fresh sonar on a new MS SQL database because previously it was on a H2 database. So the problem was temporarily fixed but today it occured again and I got the following output for a Jenkins job:

```
INFO:
------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE INFO:
------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 17.312s Final Memory: 42M/101M INFO:
------------------------------------------------------------------------ ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution ERROR: Unable to execute


Sonar ERROR: Caused by: Expected single result, but got :
[Snapshot[resourceId=774,buildDate=2014-07-16
10:39:21.243,createdAt=2014-07-16
10:39:20.0,version=1.0-SNAPSHOT,last=true,status=P,purgeStatus=1,scope=PRJ,path=946316.,depth=1,qualifier=BRC,rootId=946316,parentId=946316,rootProjectId=773,period1Mode=previous_analysis,period2Mode=days,period3Mode=previous_version,period4Mode=<null>,period5Mode=<null>,period1Param=2014-07-16,period2Param=30,period3Param=<null>,period4Param=<null>,period5Param=<null>,period1Date=2014-07-16 10:35:47.0,period2Date=2014-06-16
10:39:20.0,period3Date=<null>,period4Date=<null>,period5Date=<null>,id=946317],Snapshot[resourceId=774,buildDate=2014-07-16
10:39:29.867,createdAt=2014-07-16
10:39:29.0,version=1.0-SNAPSHOT,last=true,status=P,purgeStatus=<null>,scope=PRJ,path=946353.,depth=1,qualifier=BRC,rootId=946353,parentId=946353,rootProjectId=970,period1Mode=previous_analysis,period2Mode=days,period3Mode=previous_version,period4Mode=<null>,period5Mode=<null>,period1Param=2014-07-16,period2Param=30,period3Param=<null>,period4Param=<null>,period5Param=<null>,period1Date=2014-07-16 10:35:47.0,period2Date=2014-06-16
10:39:29.0,period3Date=<null>,period4Date=<null>,period5Date=<null>,id=946357]]
```

So there goes something wrong with the snapshot. I did some research previous time but didn't find a good solution. Is this a bug in Sonar and could it be solved in a newer version?

**SOLUTION**

In my sonar project there were also 'Components' (can be find in the GUI). These components also have snapshots. The output of sonar above here says it's looking for resource_id 774. So I selected the snapshots of this id and I saw there were two snapshots with is_last = 1.

```
SELECT * FROM snapshots where project_id=774
Order by 2 desc
```

So I updated the one before the last one so it has is_last = 0.

```
UPDATE snapshots SET islast = 0 WHERE id=yoursnapshotid
```

**SIDENOTE**

This solved the problem. As I also tried to delete some snapshots in the database (deleted the record) I ran into another problem telling me

> "Unable to find org.sonar.api.database.model.Snapshot with id x"

This problem I solved by deleting the events in the events table with snapshot_id x.

```
delete from events where snapshot_id=946316
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see that there are multiple snapshots. Please go to settings and check the snapshots. you will see multiple snapshots at the same time. you need to delete one of them. It is a sonar defect. if this is not the case or you need more help you can ask me here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did not find any duplicates I think but I deleted the snapshot at 10:35 but now it still complains about the snapshot at 10:39 (which is the last one and I can't delete this one from GUI).

Comment: i know , just send me the snapshot of this. i resolved this issues a few months back. i will tell you the approach. you may need to a few things in the database.

Comment: how can I send you the snapshot? Can you tell me exactly where to find what you need?

Comment: How many last snapshots were there before you deleted the snapshot which was timed at 10:35. if you query the database you will surely get an idea. something like this "select * from [dbo].snapshots where project_id='yourprojectid' and islast='1'".
your project id's will be 970 or 773. 
Just check this out.

Comment: My project id is indeed 773 . This is the output of the query.
946316 2014-07-16 10:39:20.993 773 NULL P 1 PRJ TRK NULL meh  0 773 previous_analysis 2014-07-16 2014-07-16 10:35:47.000 days 30 2014-06-16 10:39:20.000 previous_version NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 2014-07-16 10:39:21.180 NULL


I did only delete 1 snapshot at 10:35

Comment: I was able to solve my problem! I had a better look at the output of sonar (in my start post) and it's complaining about a snapshot with resource_id 774, not 773. 774 is a component of project with id 773 so I used "SELECT * FROM snapshots where project_id=774
Order by 2 desc" and saw there were two snapshots with set is_last to 1. I set one of them to 0. This fixed the problem

Comment: This was the exact point i was trying to make. At last this helped you. Could you please like my main response.